# subprocess interactive bash behavior

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I'm using python 3.5 on Mac OS X Sierra

The following code works as expected, printing `'hello world'` 5 times:

```
for _ in range(5):
    print(subprocess.check_output(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', 'echo hell world']))
```

while this one causes the script to stop, after printing the directory listing only once.

```
for _ in range(5):
    print(subprocess.check_output(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', 'ls']))
```

displays

```
... my directory listing ...
[2]+ Stopped    python demo.py
```

I have aliased my `ls` in `~/.bashrc` as `ls -alf`. If I remove the alias, the program seems to work fine. Is there something wrong with starting bash in interactive mode?

EDIT:

Interestingly, I can hack the command to force the correct behavior:

```
for _ in range(5):
    print(subprocess.check_output(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', 'echo; ls']))
```

Now `ls` doesn't kill the script anymore, regardless of whether it's aliased or not. Any idea?

Comment: I don't have python3 installed, but what happens if you run: `for _ in range(5):
    print(subprocess.check_output(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', 'ls -alf']))` without an alias defined in .bashrc?

Comment: Why have you the command in interactive mode!? `print(subprocess.check_output(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'ls']))` It has got nothing to do with the alias..

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran Presumably he wants to use aliases from .bashrc. But I agree the `-i` is probably why it's not working. With my python2 in cygwin, this causes the whole interpreter to stop and wait for input.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran because I want the command to run with my aliases and bash functions defined in `~/.bashrc`. `ls` here is just an illustration. I intend to use the code snippet to run something much more complicated.

Comment: @piojo thanks for the clarification. That's weird too ... `ls` should return immediately. So there is weird behavior in both py2 and py3.

Comment: @AinzTitor The normal solution is to tell bash to `source $HOME/.bashrc` rather than to run it interactively. In fact, functions are normally put in a separate file which can be sourced by your script and also by .bashrc.

Comment: @AinzTitor `ls` is probably returning immediately, but bash isn't returning at all. Though why the "-alf" alias makes any difference is a mystery to me.

Comment: I would recommend `shell=True`:  `subprocess.check_output('ls -i -c', shell=True)` which will invoke `bash` by default.

Comment: @piojo I tried to do `source .bashrc && <cmd>`, but things break in other ways. I still want to understand why the interactive mode fails.

Comment: Oh, I bet it's due to buffering--the added flags will cause longer output, and if you run bash in interactive mode, it may be trying to print the output to screen instead of to a pipe. Whatever buffer it's using is getting full, and the program deadlocks.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm not using that because it doesn't load my aliases and other things in `.bashrc`

Comment: @piojo hmm, but how about the process being stopped altogether in python3? Buffering doesn't account for that.

Comment: My environment is too different from yours for me to run meaningful tests. The way processes and threads are run differs per OS and version, and it differs on cygwin versus the native OS underneath. Shell I/O works differently between windows and cygwin and linux as well.

Comment: @piojo I should have mentioned that I'm using Mac. Edit added. Thanks for the reminder

Comment: @piojo see edit: I can hack to get the correct behavior by adding an `echo` before `ls` ...

Comment: @AinzTitor Interesting. Doesn't work for me, but it's interesting. I hope you know that this solution isn't robust, right? Until you fully understand the problem, this will probably happen again. (Running bash as interactive in a script is a hard sell. Normally, scripts only invoke interactive programs in a non-interactive state using a helper tool called "expect", which emulates a terminal and handles I/O to the interactive program.)

Comment: @piojo I agree, it's an ugly and short-lived hack.

Comment: @piojo regarding my use case, what's your suggested way to load `.bashrc`  and call subprocess with my aliases if we don't use `bash -i`?

Comment: Turn your aliases into functions so scripts can use them without hacks, move them to a separate file (which can also be sourced by your .bashrc) and run: `bash -c "source .bash/functions.sh; other commands"`. In bash, `alias foo=bar` is functionally equivalent to `function foo { bar "$@"; }`